# Tmux command mode - Use vi shortcuts

Tags: tmux, vi

In bash commandline, you can use vim shortcuts by setting `set editing-mode vi` in the `~/.inputrc` file. I want to be able do the same when typing `<prefix>:new` to create a new window for example.

(In my `~/.tmux.conf` file, i have `set-window-option -g mode-keys vi`, which does not achieve the above in the command mode.)

Comment: isn't this just `<prefix>:neww` as `:` is bound to the command prompt by default, and `neww` is an alias for `new-window` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to run the following `tmux` command:

```
set -g status-keys vi
```

Then after entering the command line (prefix-key + `:`) you can, for example, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and move left and right with the <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> keys.

Many other things you are used to with Bash command-line editing are available, too. <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>K</kbd> to scroll back through your command history, for instance.

Note: If you're used to hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the command-line try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead.